# Count year occurred from datetime

Tags: excel, counting

I have data as below:

```
amos            50       10/16/2012 10:13
amri            50       1/9/2013 9:31
andi            10       3/11/2008 10:35
andik           10       12/6/2012 16:58
anggoro         50       9/13/2012 16:14
ari_prabowo 50       11/26/2012 10:30
astra_permana   10       8/2/2010 17:40
atang           10       1/16/2009 14:39
```

I want to counting how many times such like year of `"2008", "2009", "2010", "2012", "2013"` occurred.

Comment: What format is your data in. If this is just one text string it will be difficult. If your dates are stored as dates within excel then I would explore the `COUNTIF` function

Comment: Im using custom format: m/d/yyyy h:mm

Comment: I try using countif, but i can't separate between date, month and year. searching google with sumproduct all none.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for re-formatting your data.

I would add a helper column to calculate the year

```
=YEAR($A$1)
```

Then you can use a countif on that column

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,2008)
```

Otherwise you could use a sumproduct (Excel 2003)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$10>=DATE(2008,1,1))*($A$1:$A$10<DATE(2009,1,1)))
```

Or countifs (excel 2007 +)

```
=COUNTIFS($A$1:$A$10,">=1/1/08",$A$1:$A$10,"<1/1/09")
```

Comment: Thansk Rick, it works for me. =YEAR($A$1), =COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,2008)

Comment: @HarryChandraSihombing If you're happy with the answer - please accept it by ticking, this will mark the thread solved.

Comment: For SUMPRODUCT version you can use YEAR, e.g. `=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR(A1:A10)=2008))`

Comment: ....also for the SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS versions using `<=31/12/2008` can cause miscounting because the data includes times so an entry like 12/31/2008 11:30 wouldn't be counted, better to use `<1/1/09`